# flutter- !_debugLocked is not true

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, debugging

I have this problem , when I try to use navigator this error will show up

```
[+1368632 ms] Error: Assertion failed: file:///home/saeedszz/snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/navigator.dart:4564:12
          !_debugLocked
          is not true
```

I tried everything inside relevant topics in StackOverflow and non of them seemed to work
thank you in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this line of code before using Navigator Solved my problem

```
 await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
```

Comment: That worked, Thank you! 
Would be nice if someone could explain why the error happened in the first place and why the delay could solve it